# truthy doesn't work with sbt new

Tags: sbt, giter8

I've created a template project with giter8, and trying to add conditional expression.

in the `defaults.properties` I added:

```
param=true
```

and in the template file I added:

```
  $if(param.truthy)$
  ....
  $endif$
```

when I'm generating the project with:

```
g8 file://proj.g8
```

everything works as expected.
in the interactive part, `param` would have 2 options:

> param **[YES/no]**:

and the generated file will include the additional text based on the value of the `param`

But, when I generate the project with:

```
sbt new file://proj.g8
```

`param` is being treated as a string.
during the interactive part, there are no yes/no options:

> param **[yes]**:

and I'm getting the following error:

> Exiting due to error in the template File:
>   /tmp/giter8-135496483100759/src/main/g8/build.sbt, context [anonymous]
>   44:6 internal error: org.stringtemplate.v4.compiler.STException:
>   context [anonymous] 44:6 no such property or can't access:
>   java.lang.String.truthy Caused by:
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.STNoSuchPropertyException: no such
>   property: java.lang.String.truthy     at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.throwNoSuchProperty(ObjectModelAdaptor.java:167)
>     at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ObjectModelAdaptor.getProperty(ObjectModelAdaptor.java:89)
>     at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.getObjectProperty(Interpreter.java:1200)
>     at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:210)    at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)  at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.write(ST.java:427)   at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.render(ST.java:497)  at
>   org.clapper.scalasti.ST.render(ST.scala:285)  at
>   giter8.G8$.applyTemplate(g8.scala:102)    at
>   giter8.G8$.write(g8.scala:154)    at giter8.G8$.write(g8.scala:138)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$writeTemplates$3(g8.scala:396)    at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:242)
>     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)    at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:242)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$writeTemplates$2(g8.scala:396)    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:530)   at
>   giter8.G8$.writeTemplates(g8.scala:386)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$applyT$1(g8.scala:257)    at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:702)   at
>   giter8.G8$.applyT(g8.scala:249)   at
>   giter8.G8$.fromDirectory(g8.scala:62)     at
>   giter8.JgitHelper$.$anonfun$run$3(JgitHelper.scala:64)    at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:702)   at
>   giter8.JgitHelper$.run(JgitHelper.scala:63)   at
>   giter8.Giter8.$anonfun$run$2(giter8.scala:34)     at
>   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)    at
>   giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:33)    at
>   sbtgiter8resolver.Giter8TemplateResolver.run(Giter8TemplateResolver.scala:31)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.call(TemplateCommand.scala:100)  at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:78)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1(TemplateCommand.scala:58)     at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(TemplateCommand.scala:54)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:108)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.find(List.scala:86)  at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.run(TemplateCommand.scala:54)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:41)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$templateCommand$2(TemplateCommand.scala:24)
>     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:134)   at
>   sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:130)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:153)  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:136)     at
>   sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:242)   at
>   sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:248)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:136)     at
>   sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
>     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:136)   at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:129)     at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)    at
>   sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)   at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)    at
>   sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)  at
>   sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
>
> at giter8.G8$STErrorHandler.runTimeError(g8.scala:110)  at
>   giter8.G8$STErrorHandler.runTimeError(g8.scala:105)   at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.misc.ErrorManager.runTimeError(ErrorManager.java:137)
>     at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.getObjectProperty(Interpreter.java:1203)
>     at org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter._exec(Interpreter.java:210)    at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.Interpreter.exec(Interpreter.java:145)  at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.write(ST.java:427)   at
>   org.stringtemplate.v4.ST.render(ST.java:497)  at
>   org.clapper.scalasti.ST.render(ST.scala:285)  at
>   giter8.G8$.applyTemplate(g8.scala:102)    at
>   giter8.G8$.write(g8.scala:154)    at giter8.G8$.write(g8.scala:138)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$writeTemplates$3(g8.scala:396)    at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.$anonfun$opt$1(Exception.scala:242)
>     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)    at
>   scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.opt(Exception.scala:242)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$writeTemplates$2(g8.scala:396)    at
>   scala.collection.immutable.Stream.foreach(Stream.scala:530)   at
>   giter8.G8$.writeTemplates(g8.scala:386)   at
>   giter8.G8$.$anonfun$applyT$1(g8.scala:257)    at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:702)   at
>   giter8.G8$.applyT(g8.scala:249)   at
>   giter8.G8$.fromDirectory(g8.scala:62)     at
>   giter8.JgitHelper$.$anonfun$run$3(JgitHelper.scala:64)    at
>   scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:702)   at
>   giter8.JgitHelper$.run(JgitHelper.scala:63)   at
>   giter8.Giter8.$anonfun$run$2(giter8.scala:34)     at
>   scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)    at
>   giter8.Giter8.run(giter8.scala:33)    at
>   sbtgiter8resolver.Giter8TemplateResolver.run(Giter8TemplateResolver.scala:31)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.call(TemplateCommand.scala:100)  at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:78)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1(TemplateCommand.scala:58)     at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$run$1$adapted(TemplateCommand.scala:54)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>     at
>   scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.find$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:108)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.find(List.scala:86)  at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.run(TemplateCommand.scala:54)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.runTemplate(TemplateCommand.scala:41)    at
>   sbt.TemplateCommandUtil$.$anonfun$templateCommand$2(TemplateCommand.scala:24)
>     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:134)   at
>   sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:130)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:153)  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:136)     at
>   sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:242)   at
>   sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:248)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:136)     at
>   sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
>     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:136)   at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:129)     at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)    at
>   sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)   at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)    at
>   sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)  at
>   sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

I'm using version `0.11.0-M3` for both `g8` and `sbt-giter8` plugin

How can I fix this problem?

EDIT: some more details:
I'm using sbt 1.1.1 (for both the g8 project and the sbt launcher on my machine)
I added the plugin in the g8 project in the file `project/plugins.sbt` with

```
addSbtPlugin("org.foundweekends.giter8" %% "sbt-giter8" % "0.11.0-M3")
```

if I remove the truthy parts from the template, the project is generated correctly from `sbt new`

---

This issue been fixed in sbt 1.2.0
in order to fix, should use:

`sbt -Dsbt.version=1.2.0 new  file://proj.g8`

Comment: Which version of sbt are you using? And how do you setup `sbt-giter8` plugin?

Comment: I added more details to the qiestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of giter8 used internally for `sbt new` is fixed and adding `sbt-giter8` plugin won't change it. sbt 1.1.1 [uses](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.1.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/plugins/Giter8ResolverPlugin.scala#L26) sbt-giter8-resolver v0.1.3, which [uses](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/blob/v0.1.3/project/Dependencies.scala#L6) giter8 0.7.2 (which doesn't support conditionals).

You could update sbt-giter8-resolver, publish it locally and try to replace the default [`Giter8TemplatePlugin`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/v1.1.1/main/src/main/scala/sbt/plugins/Giter8ResolverPlugin.scala), but I think it's not worth it. Just use `g8` directly until sbt gets updated.

There [was an effort](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/pull/344) to support arbitrary giter8 version [set *in the template*](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-giter8-resolver/issues/11), but something [went wrong](https://github.com/foundweekends/giter8/issues/364) and this feature has been reverted.

Comment: Many users are using that template, and I don't want to force them to install giter8. For now I just won't use the conditions. Thanks.